# Kafka Streaming - Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException - Too many open files

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Using Kafka Streaming 2.4 and DSL API.

I am having stateful streaming processing which connects to user topic having 100 partitions. application also refers internal topics which has default partitions similler to user topic.

Observing Below Error and all task threads are getting shut down eventually.

Could you please put some pointer on getting formula to calculate required open file descriptors?

```
public  class CustomRocksDBConfig implements RocksDBConfigSetter {
private org.rocksdb.Cache cache = new org.rocksdb.LRUCache(2 * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L);
@Override
public void setConfig(final String storeName, final Options options, final Map<String, Object> configs) {
    BlockBasedTableConfig tableConfig = (BlockBasedTableConfig) options.tableFormatConfig();
    tableConfig.setBlockCache(cache);
    tableConfig.setBlockCacheSize(1024L * 1024L * 1024L);
    tableConfig.setBlockSize( 4 * 1024L);
    tableConfig.setCacheIndexAndFilterBlocks(true);
    options.setTableFormatConfig(tableConfig);
    options.setMaxWriteBufferNumber(7);
    options.setMinWriteBufferNumberToMerge(4);
    options.setWriteBufferSize(25 * 1024L * 1024L);}
Caused by: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: While open a file for appending: /data/directory/generator.1583280000000/002360.sst: Too many open files
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.flush(Native Method)
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.flush(RocksDB.java:2394)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore$SingleColumnFamilyAccessor.flush(RocksDBStore.java:581)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.flush(RocksDBStore.java:384)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: Please share your configs `ulimit -a` ,

Comment: Thank you for reply.  nofile= 65535, nproc=163840, pipe buffer size=4096,socket buffer size=4096, sigpend=257587, stack size=10240, core file size=0,locked address space=64,nice=0,rtprio=0   rest is unlimited or unsupported. RockedDB can custom configured withen streaming app but formula to calculate required open file descriptor is unknown. Please let me know if you can put some direction.

Comment: Trying to understand:  [link] (https://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html) [link] (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html)

Comment: You may need to increase the open file limit on your operating system. -- It's very hard to estimate the number of required file descriptors as it depends on many factors. In doubt, you may want to reach out to the RocksDB community.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax - Thank you for reply. With default configuration and given generated key, kafka streaming does put to in MemTable and instantly create sst to store on statestore directory. My expectation was flushing when all 3 memtables gets full. Advantage of this accessing less sst files and limiting opening or creating multiple files

Comment: Hard to say. Note that Kafka Streams flushed every 30 second and write everything to disk. Maybe that is the reason?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax - Probably thats the reason. we are proceeding with increasing nlimit on servers. and additionally increased kafka streaming cache size from default to x MB based on initially analysis. This config helped us to compact records in cache for default commit interval which is 30 sec. Config - cache.max.bytes.buffering

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax - Regarding your point "Kafka Streams flushed every 30 second and write everything to disk"  Is it because default commit interval to 30 secs?  Kafka streaming  and Rock Db both referring  to same commit interval which contradicts facebook rockdb documentation. probably kafka streaming has customized it.  https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksDB-Tuning-Guide  
Flushing options

Comment: Yes, I am referring to Kafka Streams configuration `commit.interval.ms` with default value of 30 seconds. It triggers an explicit `RocksDB.flush()` call.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax  PART1 : My requirement is to delay flush to the disk by setting custom rocksdb config but keeping default commit interval.
 
Streaming is sending compacted keys to statestore once commit interval completes and I would like rocksDB to wait flushing to the disk. 

Facebook has pointed out in the documentation about merging minimum read only memtables and flushing when they fills up(which might take more than 30 sec depending upon memtables size)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax PART2: To achieve this behavior implemented CustomRockDBConfig class and set it to streaming property - rocksdb.config.setter. 
Observed that all these properties are being set correctly when application starts up. 

Reference Link - https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html (Section-rocksdb.config.setter)

I have explicitly settings for disk flush after 4 memtables fills up and not to relay on commit interval 
but observed that rocksDb using default commit interval even with explicit custom class.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax PART3: Senario:
1) Send 5 records(each having 800 bytes) with same key/value to stateful streaming application  withen 30 sec interval.
2) Records get compacted into only one record. 
3) Record gets flushed to the disk as soon as default commit interval completes and it does not wait till memtables(4*25MB=100MB) fills up.
 
Please refer sample code in the description.
Appreciate your help understanding this system behavior.

Comment: `My requirement is to delay flush to the disk by setting custom rocksdb config but keeping default commit interval.` -- I don't think that is possible. If you want to get less flushing, you need to increase the commit interval.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax - Thank you Matt for your help. Sorry for asking one more question and get your opinion. Outcome of our discussion is: "Streaming app has to depend on commit interval for disk flushing". Does it mean that Kafka DSL API explicitly overides/suppress rocksDB internal flushing behavior?

Comment: I guess you can phrase it that way because Kafka Streams will call `RocksDB.flush()` explicitly on commit and thus force a flush.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thank you matt for your reply. Any chance you can provide me that class name? It will help from knowledge standpoint. as a further steps we are increasing nlimit and cache.max.bytes.buffering

Comment: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/internals/RocksDBStore.java should help as a starting point.

Comment: Issue solved after increasing ulimit.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved after incrementing ulimit.